# How can I get my script to execute on a textbox input change in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using the [Farbtastic](https://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/) color picker to change values in an HTML input text box. I have it programmed so that when the hex value inside the  text box is changed, it is supposed to execute a JavaScript function that converts the hex value to RGB and sends it to a device that changes the color of an LED light. I've successfully tested this using a button to perform the script, so I'm fairly certain that the function isn't the problem

Here's the relevant HTML code:

```
<div id="colorpicker"></div>
        <md-input>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Color</label>
                <input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" ng-model="color" ng-change="return hexToRGB(document.getElementById('color').value);"/>
            </md-input-container>
        </md-input>
```

The `ng-change` seems to be the root of the issue. Is there something I need to change here? Or is there something else that needs to be fixed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deathhell/UTn5y/2/ That should be a start

Comment: How does this help? I'm not sure how this is relevant.

Comment: Sorry, i thought the user was updating the input text box, and not via the color picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return` keyword.

Change:

`ng-change="return hexToRGB(document.getElementById('color').value);"`

To:

`ng-change="hexToRGB(document.getElementById('color').value);"`